# I am trying to add comments withour refresh a page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

When I try to add a comment, it doesnt append on table. When i refresh a page then it append. I dont know what is problem. I think I did everything well. There is no errors on page. And it goes in table whatever I add to table, but only after refresh a page.

show.html.erb

```html
...
<table id="comments">
  <tbody>
    <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
...
```

_comment.html.erb

```html
<tr>
  <td><p><%= comment.name %></p></td>
  <td><p><%= comment.body %></p></td>
  <td><p><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p></td>
  <% if User.find_by(email: comment.name) == current_user %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  <% else %>
    <td> </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

create.js.erb

```js
$('table#comments tbody').append("<%= j render @comment %>")
```

terminal

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'search/index'

  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/index'
  get '/search', to: 'search#search'



  resources :user
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
    member do
      put "like" => "articles#like"
      put "unlike" => "articles#unlike"
    end
  end
  resources :search, only: [:index]

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    @comment.name = current_user.email
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.js 
            format.html { redirect_to @comment }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
        else

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: in your controller need to render as `js` format, also - the comment should be submitted using `remote: true`

Comment: I edit question and add my controller also. Can you take a look and tell me where I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default, format return from controller is `html`. So you need to add another formant `js` in controller to make `js.erb` work.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be something like this:

```
def create
 ............ 
 if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end 
end
```

to handle the errors: in `create.js.erb` file, check `@comment.errors.any?` - then do whatever you want to do.